# ffmpeg android, no such file or directory for image only

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I have a problem using ffmpeg on android device. I have built a static ffmpeg using guardian project, which I use as command line in android. Now my problem is that my code works fine and all for quite a few device, but for some reason on some device(like Nivo) it just fails.

To be more precise it only fails when I use **image as an input**. My command has two -i input defined with a complex filter overlaying one on another. Now if I use two video it works like a charm. If I use an image as the second input then it fails saying:

**/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/picture_1389105356533.png: No such file or directory**

**The file exists I checked it**

And to make it even more interesting this only happens on some device like the bloody Nivo, generally it works great ( Samsung s2, samsung s4, nexus 7, nexus 4 etc)

Any idea?

**Update1**
What I don't get is when I build the guardian project I get **ffmpeg version 0.11.1** even though I thought it should auto update the ffmpeg inside it... And as far as I know ffmpeg is around version 2+ now?

Comment: Add the code where you are giving the `file path`.

Comment: I get the file path from android, so that's not the issue. it's a correct file path like /mnt/storage/image.jpg and I checked it from file browser the image is there.

Comment: is this error occurring for all images or only for `*.png` ?

Comment: Same with jpg "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20131231_192515.jpg: No such file or directory" And the funny part is that it recognizes the movie input correctly.

Comment: And even if I copy the image beside the ffmpeg executable and just use bunny.jpg as input, same result "bunny.jpg: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with a fresh build. I didn't figured out only recently that the guardian project for some reason didn't update ffmpeg above 0.11.1 version or something like that. So I asked help on the ffmpeg irc chat to build a new one from ground. That work on every device.

Comment: Kindly provide that library with us because this is the same problem i am facing right now.

Comment: please provide that library or tell the way to get correct library .

Comment: I ended up building one for my self. I cloned the newest ffmepg from git:

git clone git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg

Answer (score 2):

Ok finally I think I found the loophole; here it is.

The `guardian Ffmpeg` build that you have used has following in the `configure_ffmpeg.sh`:

> --cpu=cortex-a8 \  <== The problem :)

While the device you successfully tested are `Above` or `Equal` to this Cpu. But for `nivo`; the it is `Cortex A5` which is less than the specified flag.

So just make a change here and you are good to go..!!

Cheers.

Comment: what should I add instead of cortex-a8? But I still don't get it why would it work with movies... and fail on images

Comment: Did you just try after removing `--cpu...` line ? Also if it doesnt work try after removing `--extra-cflags=...` because it complements `cortex-a8`.

Comment: K, I have another issue with sequential video playing, after I solved that I recompile it and post back the result if it worked.

Comment: You can post other doubt as a new question.

Comment: I did it already, cuz it's getting on my nerves quite a while now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017613/ffmpeg-itsoffset-with-overlay-command

Comment: It didn't solve my issue. I tried both removing cpu config and cflags, without any success :'(