# FFMPEG, itsoffset with overlay command not working as it supposed to

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I managed to overlay two videos one by another with the overlay command and use a nullsrc command to play both video till both of them ended with the following command:

```
./ffmpeg -i first.MOV -i second.MOV -filter_complex "nullsrc=size=1280x400:duration=30[bg];[0]scale=640:-1,pad=1280:400[first];[bg][first]overlay=0:0[base];[1]scale=640:-1[second];[base][second]overlay=640:0" output.mp4
```

Now what I wanted to do is to delay one of the overlay till the other one finishes. For this as far as I know the command is itsoffset, so I modified to use this:

```
./ffmpeg -i first.MOV -itsoffset 5 -i second.MOV -filter_complex "nullsrc=size=1280x400:duration=30[bg];[0]scale=640:-1,pad=1280:400[first];[bg][first]overlay=0:0[base];[1]scale=640:-1[second];[base][second]overlay=640:0" output.mp4
```

Now my only problem with this is that I want to show the first frame of the delayed video till it starts... And even though somewhere I read that this should do it, it won't. It leaves it blank till the input starts.

Any idea how could I add the first frame of second video till the itsoffset starts the video?

**Update1:** I may found a cheat around it, but the problem with it it's  really slow in the first second or so.

```
./ffmpeg -i first.MOV -i second.MOV -itsoffset 5 -i second.MOV -filter_complex "color=size=1280x400:duration=30[bg];[1]select=eq(n\,0),scale=640:-1[fg];[bg][fg]overlay=640:0[bgc];[0]scale=640:-1[first];[bgc][first]overlay=0:0[firstb];[2]scale=640:-1[second];[firstb][second]overlay=640:0" output.mp4
```

Not to mention later on I need to dynamically create the command line string which would be really painful like this.

Comment: You should also show you complete `ffmpeg` console output for at least one of your commands.

Comment: Why is the output relevant if it's not an error, it just not working as I thought it would? Plus even though if it's a console command it's still almost as complex as coding, so why wouldn't it belong here?

Comment: The console output contains more than just errors, but information on how `ffmpeg` was configured and information on your inputs. It will also show if you're even using FFmpeg or a fork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solution I ended up something like this:

```
./ffmpeg -i first.MOV -i second.MOV -itsoffset 5 -i second.MOV -filter_complex "color=size=1280x400:duration=30[bg];[1]select=eq(n\,0),scale=640:-1[fg];[bg][fg]overlay=640:0[bgc];[0]scale=640:-1[first];[bgc][first]overlay=0:0[firstb];[2]scale=640:-1[second];[firstb][second]overlay=640:0" output.mp4
```

The only problem with this I got was that for some reason the audio waasn't delayed and the overlaying images got lagging and the timestep was a bit messed up. Finally I just figured out that I need to use -async 1 and it started working like a magic. First frame showing up from the begining, audio delayed with video etc.

**So the final command should look like this:**

```
./ffmpeg -i first.MOV -i second.MOV -itsoffset 5 -i second.MOV -filter_complex "color=size=1280x400:duration=30[bg];[1]select=eq(n\,0),scale=640:-1[fg];[bg][fg]overlay=640:0[bgc];[0]scale=640:-1[first];[bgc][first]overlay=0:0[firstb];[2]scale=640:-1[second];[firstb][second]overlay=640:0" -async 1 output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

your command working perfectly in case of video but audio of second input is not playing.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!! This can be a comment.