# Android ffmpeg Issue :- <filepath> : No such file or directory

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I am using FFMPEG tool to merge IMAGE & AUDIO files. Its working only in SAMSUNG GALAXY TAB II.
I had tried in many android devices & emulators but unfortunately it had not worked in any of them.

Same issue is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974981/ffmpeg-android-no-such-file-or-directory-for-image-only) also. But Its solutions has not worked for me.

Following is error log of emulator,

```
02-15 08:46:33.667: D/NIRAV(921): Shell Line : /data/data/org.ffmpeg.android/lib/libffmpeg.so -y -loop 1 -r 1 -i /mnt/sdcard/ffmpeg/img.jpg -i /mnt/sdcard/ffmpeg/myrecord.mp4 -acodec aac -vcodec mpeg4 -s 480x320 -strict experimental -b:a 32k -shortest -f mp4 -r 2 /mnt/sdcard/ffmpeg/out.mp4 
02-15 08:46:33.707: D/NIRAV(921): Shell Line : ffmpeg version 0.11.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
02-15 08:46:33.717: D/NIRAV(921): Shell Line :   built on Nov 15 2013 00:50:10 with gcc 4.6 20120106 (prerelease)
02-15 08:46:33.717: D/NIRAV(921): Shell Line :   configuration: --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --target-os=linux --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-small --prefix=/data/data/info.guardianproject.ffmpeg/app_opt --enable-pic --disable-shared --enable-static --cross-prefix=/home/n8fr8/dev/android/ndk//toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --sysroot=/home/n8fr8/dev/android/ndk//platforms/android-3/arch-arm --extra-cflags='-I../x264 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon' --extra-ldflags=-L../x264 --enable-version3 --enable-gpl --disable-doc --enable-yasm --enable-decoders --enable-encoders --enable-muxers --enable-demuxers --enable-parsers --enable-protocols --enable-filters --enable-avresample --enable-libfreetype --disable-indevs --enable-indev=lavfi --disable-outdevs --enable-hwaccels --enable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-network --enable-libx264 --enable-zlib --enable-muxer=md5
02-15 08:46:33.717: D/NIRAV(921): Shell Line :   libavutil      51. 54.100 / 51. 54.100
02-15 08:46:33.717: D/NIRAV(921): Shell Line :   libavcodec     54. 23.100 / 54. 23.100
02-15 08:46:33.717: D/NIRAV(921): Shell Line :   libavformat    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
02-15 08:46:33.717: D/NIRAV(921): Shell Line :   libavdevice    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
02-15 08:46:33.727: D/NIRAV(921): Shell Line :   libavfilter     2. 77.100 /  2. 77.100
02-15 08:46:33.727: D/NIRAV(921): Shell Line :   libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
02-15 08:46:33.727: D/NIRAV(921): Shell Line :   libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
02-15 08:46:33.727: D/NIRAV(921): Shell Line :   libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
02-15 08:46:33.747: D/NIRAV(921): Shell Line : /mnt/sdcard/ffmpeg/img.jpg: No such file or directory
02-15 08:46:33.747: D/NIRAV(921): Exit Value : 1
```

I had verified the path of `img.jpg` & `myrecord.mp4` files.
I am using `android-ndk-r7` to build ffmpeg.

Comment: Hi Nirav, have you find any workaround for this issue ?

Comment: @Kalpesh No, Still i didn't find the exact solution. I think there is a problem with storing out.mp4 files into the sdcard. If I am going to store out.mp4 file into internal memory (/data/data/com.myapp/cache) then it is working fine. So, temporarily it had solved my issue. (Not recommended)

Comment: @Kalpesh if you found any solution then your answer would valuable for me.

Comment: OK np...Thanks for your response.

Comment: Hi Nirav, How it's working in internal storage, Can you please share your ffmpeg commands with me?